# Able to find Qt5 library with target_link_libraries, but not with find_library. What gives?

Tags: cmake, qt5

I noticed a strange behavior when trying to change some existing code. What I noticed is that we call `target_link_libraries()` and this finds a Qt5 library with no issues, but calling `find_library()` doesn't find the same library. Here's the code I have:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${QT_ROOT})
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(projectName Qt5::Widgets)
find_library(QTWIDGETSFOUND NAMES Qt5::Widgets)
message(STATUS ${QTWIDGETSFOUND})
```

The result of this is:

```
QTWIDGETSFOUND-NOTFOUND
```

However, if I look into a generated file, `link.txt`, I can find this line:

```
/home/user/Documents/work/test/build/venv/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.3/org/dev/package/80043e232e8ab07f4b25e67652a9490d9ad33d91/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.11.3
```

I conclude that `target_link_libraries()` can find the `Qt5:Widgets` library, but `find_library()` cannot. I find this behavior quite strange.

My use case is that I want to target my library, which I do just fine, but then get the path to the library it found and copy that library file somewhere. I can't find a way to get a path from `target_link_libraries()`, so I figured that I would just call `find_library()` after to get the path of that library and copy it from there. The only possible answer I see to my problem is that `Qt5:Widgets` isn't the actual name of the library, but that `target_link_libraries()` can resolve it from the `find_package()` statement I made above and that `find_library()` isn't able to for some reason.

So, here are my questions:

1. Why is the piece of code I porived not doing what I thought it would do?
2. How can I make `find_library()` work in the provided code sample?
3. If no one can find a solution for the above, what other ways could I get a path to a library I just linked with `target_link_libraries()` other than `find_library()` that would be simple?

Thanks!

Comment: `Qt5::Widgets` as any string in form `XXX::YYY` denotes **IMPORTED target**, not a *library file*. Command `target_link_libraries` detects if its argument is a target, and extract appropriate properties from it. `find_library` searches the library **file**, it doesn't work with *targets*. You may try to extract [IMPORTED_LOCATION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) property for the target `Qt5::Widgets`, usually this property contains location of the library file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for replying! Would calling `target_link_libraries` with `Qt5::Widgets` be the same as with `Qt5Widgets`?